# Seeking 2010 County Shapefile for China?

Tags: geospatial, county, china

I have been researching frantically for the China 2010 dataset for county boundaries. I went through quite a few sources:

China Data Center - Can't afford it

GADM.org - Not verfiable for date

This is mostly 2000 Census: https://research.cip.cgiar.org/gis/modules.php?name=Downloads&d_op=viewdownload&cid=11&min=20&orderby=titleA&show=10

Can anybody help me get the 2010 county boundaries shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

This question has answers on the GIS site - [see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/4013/112869) (although not specific to the 2010 border)

In particular, for the OSM answer, I've recently written two answers which may be relevant: [osm 1](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12434/1511), [osm 2](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511)

Unfortunately, the oldest datasets seem to be from 2014-01-01 ([source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167728/112869))